# how to add normal pages instead of dialog for entities in jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

I just started using jhipster. Whenever I create a new entity, its crud is generated automatically and all works properly.

But the add//edit entity pages open in a dialog. Is there any way we can not use dialog and just show normal pages for add and edit?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the entity.js file generated by JHipster for each entity. There you can see the different angular states generated. You'll have to basically use the same structure the `state(entity.detail` has inside and apply it to the `state(entity.edit`.